# How can I capture the JavaScript events when someone reloads the page or clicks on a link?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

For example, with a slow internet connection the page might take a few seconds to load.

When a user presses reload or clicks *any* link on the page, I would like to show a message such as: "The page is loading..."

I can't add the `onclick` event for all of the links in the page, nor do that with the browser's reload button; is there is even an event for that?

Thanks for your reply!

Comment: What in the name of all that is holy does this question mean?

Comment: I have edited the post, I think preserving the intended meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `document.onbeforeunload` handler at the top of your `<head>` section so it executes as soon as possible:

```
<head>
    <script>
        window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
          return "The page is loading... Are You Sure?"
        };

        window.onload = function(e) {
            document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = 'Loaded';
            window.onbeforeunload = function() { };
        }
    </script>

    <title>Loading</title>
    ...
</head>
...
```

Comment: This is what Gmail or other web-based apps use to prompt users before leaving the page in the middle of an action, like composing a message.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at a javascript library like jQuery.

Comment: But I'm writing the MOD for other app, adding a ton of js for just one function is not good!

Comment: You're wrong. jQuery is the answer. Always. Not using it is blasphemy ;-) </sarcasm>